# Proving properties of $\sin(\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove an inequality with a $\sin$ function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213382/prove-an-inequality-with-a-sin-function)

prove that $$\sin\theta\geq \frac{2}{\pi}\theta$$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$
My idea was to divide by $\theta$ take a $\lim$ when theta goes to $0$. But it only works for small $\theta$, not for the entire interval...

Comment: use $f(x)=\sin x$ is concave on $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$f(x)=\sin x-\frac{2}{\pi}x$$
Take it's derivative and find regions of increase/decrease in the region to find its minimum value and use this to prove your result.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}\geq 1$$
since $\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ is decreasing on $\theta \in (0,\pi/2]$.