# Mean Value Theorem: $\frac{2}{\pi}<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

I need to show that $\dfrac{2}{\pi}<\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}<1$ for $0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

I know I need to use the mean value theorem, would I just say that since $f$ is continuous in the interval (call it I).

We know $\exists c\in I$ such that $f'(c) = \dfrac{f\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)-f(0)}{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$. I don't know where this is going though.

Also, would I need to show $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$? Is there a way to do this without L'H Rule?

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x}=\left.\frac{\text d\sin x}{\text dx}\right|_{x=0}=\cos 0=1$$

Comment: @Tim note that *often* the limit of $\sin(x)/x$ is used to evaluate $\sin '(0)$.

Comment: @pppqqq I'm aware, but usually the derivative of sine (for some reason) is seen as more fundamental (also, this is equivalent to solving it by L'Hopital, which is common).  If OP is looking for full rigor, he/she can find it [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Sine_of_X_over_X#Geometric_Proof).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213382/prove-an-inequality-with-a-sin-function-sinx-frac2-pi-x-for-0x-fr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove an inequality with a $\sin$ function: $\sin(x) &gt; \frac2\pi x$ for $0&lt;x&lt;\frac\pi2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213382/prove-an-inequality-with-a-sin-function-sinx-frac2-pi-x-for-0x-fr)

Comment: Here is another way to do this. Define $f(x)=\sin x-\dfrac{2x}{\pi}$ Now note that the double derivative of the function $f''(x)=-\sin x$ which is $<0$ for all $x\in\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)$. This gives that $f(x)$ is concave. Moreover as $f(0)=f(\frac{\pi}{2})$, we get that $f(x)\ge 0$ which gives $\sin x\ge \dfrac{2x}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ then we know that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = 1$ (its a pretty standard limit with a standard geometric proof: see [this blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-4.html) under "Proof of Standard Limits"). Let us define $f(0) = 1$ to make $f(x)$ continuous on $[0, \pi/2]$. Now we can see that $$f'(x) = \dfrac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x^{2}}$$ Now we know that if $x \in (0, \pi/2)$ then we have the inequality $x < \tan x$ (see the geometric proof of this in the blog post referred earlier) so that $x\cos x < \sin x$ and thus $f'(x) < 0$ in $(0, \pi/2)$. It follows by Mean value theorem that if $x \in (0, \pi/2)$ then we have $$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = f'(c_{1}) < 0$$ so that $f(x) < f(0)$ i.e. $\dfrac{\sin x}{x} < 1$. And again $$\frac{f(\pi/2) - f(x)}{(\pi/2) - x} = f'(c_{2}) < 0$$ so that $f(\pi/2) < f(x)$ and then $\dfrac{2}{\pi} < \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ and we are done.

Comment: amazing..........:)

Answer (score 2):

I will prove that $\frac{2x}{\pi}<\sin x < x$,  for all $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Proof:

First I'll use the fact that if functions $f,g$ are continuous on $[a,b)$ and diffrentiable on $(a,b)$, and satisfies $f(a)\leq g(a)$, $f'(x)\leq g'(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, then $f(x)\leq g(x)$ to all $x\in [a,b)$.

We are ready to prove $\sin x < x$ for all $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Let us define $f(x)=\sin x-x$. We will get

$$f(0)=0$$

$$f'(x)=\cos x -1$$

Hence, $f(x)\leq 0$  for all $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. To prove that instead of "$\leq$" there is "$<$" we use Rolle's theorem. Suppose that there is $x_0\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ for which $f(x_0)=0$; then all Rolle's theorem conditions are satisfied on the closed interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, and therefore there must be  a point $c\in (0,x_0) $ such that $f'(c)=0$. But $f'(x)=0$ iff $\cos x =1$, which then $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, and that is a contradiction. We deduce that for all $x_0\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ there $f(x_0)<0$, and hence we have that for all $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have $\sin x <x$.

Now we define $g(x)=\frac{2x}{\pi}-\sin x$. And we have that $g(0)=0$. But in this case we have some problem:

$$g'(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}-\cos x$$

When $\frac{2}{\pi}-\cos x=0$, we have $\cos x= \frac{2}{\pi}$, we deduce that there is another solution which is obtained on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. 
If we look more carefully, we will see that there is only one solution for that equation, in other words the derivative is zero only in one point. Also, we notice that

$$g(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin (\frac{\pi}{2})=1-1=0$$

Again, all Rolle's theorem conditions are satisfied for $g(x)$ on the closed $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ (and in every sub interval). It is impossible that for $x_0\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ there $g(x_0)=0$. Now, if $x_1\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ it is also impossible to have $g(x_1)>0$, because from the continuity of $g(x)$, $g(x)$ must have zero on   $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Therefore, for all $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ we have $g(x)<0$, thus $\frac{2x}{\pi}<\sin x$.

Comment: The English is bad(!), I welcome you to edit.

Comment: "... iff $\cos x=1 \Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{2}$" Shouldn't x=0 for f$\prime (x)=0$?

Comment: Yes, this was the mistake for the contradiction. I actually just asked myself that.

Answer (score 0):

**First proof using mean value Theorem**
Let $0 < x < \pi/2$ be fixed. By Mean value theorem
there exists $y \in (0, x)$ such that
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}= \cos(y).$$
Similarly  there exists $z \in (x, \pi/2)$ such that
$$\frac{1-\sin(x)}{\pi/2- x}= \cos(z).$$
As $0 < y < z< \pi/2$ and $\cos$ is a strictly decreasing function in $[0, \pi/2]$ we see that $ \cos (z) < \cos (y).$
Thus $$\frac{1-\sin(x)}{\pi/2- x} < \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\implies \frac{1-\sin(x)}{\sin(x)} < \frac{\pi/2- x}{x}.$$
$$\implies\frac{1}{\sin(x)}- 1< \frac{\pi}{2x}- 1\implies \frac{2}{\pi}< \frac{\sin (x)}{x}.$$
Since $y \in (0, \pi/2)$, therefore
$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}= \cos(y) <1.$
Hence for any $0 < x < \pi/2$, we get
$$\frac 2 \pi<\frac{\sin(x)}{x}<1.$$

**Second proof** consider the function
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin{x}}{x} \quad\implies f'(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x^2}~~ \text{with} \quad g(x) = x\cos{x} -\sin{x} $$
and
$$g'(x) = -x\sin{x}\le 0$$
For $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have $g'(x) \le 0$, then $g$ is decreasing whereas  $g(0) = 0 $.

Thus $g(x) \le 0$ on this interval. As a result, $f'(x) \le 0$ too, hence $f$ is decreasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. That is $or ~~~0\le x\le \pi/2$ we have  $$1=f(0)>\frac{\sin{x}}{x} =f(x) > f(\pi/2) =\frac{2}{\pi}$$