# functions $\sin(x)/x$ is between $1$ and $2/\pi $

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

We have to prove that for $0 < x < \pi/2$ ; $1 > \frac{\sin(x)}{x} > \frac{2}{\pi}$ . This is a simple problem . I just want to know what I am doing is correct or not . At $0$ function is very close to $1$ and $f(\pi/2) = 2/\pi$  .

If I prove that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing in this domain , then that will be enough , isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, that will be enough.

Comment: @EricAuld Thank you :) !

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/596634/ and I have provided the answer based on the decreasing nature of $f(x)$. So you are on right track.