# Riemann integrable (University of hyderabad 2017 exam)

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I know that the function is continuous at $x=0$ by sequential criteria but I can't figure out the Riemann integrability of this function:

Consider $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$  defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \sin x, & x \in [-1,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \\ 0, & x \notin [-1,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$
Then at $x=0$, $f$ is

(A) continuous and Riemann integrable in every interval $(a,b)$ containing $0$.

(B) continuous and Riemann integrable in exactly one interval $(a,b)$ containing $0$.

(C) continuous but not Riemann integrable in any interval containing $x$

(D) discontinuos.

Comment: use Lebesgue’s Criterion for Riemann integrability.

Comment: It's piecewise continuous and bounded.

Comment: It is c,  the right one.

Comment: It's not piecewise continuous; its continuous only at $0$. And it is not Riemann integrable on any interval containing $0$ because you can always pick partitions with rational (resp. irrational) tags.

Comment: In order to be integrable it must have zero measure of discontinouties.

Comment: Is there any way to do it using Darboux integral? It was aksed in M. Sc entrance exam and measure is not in b. Sc syllabus..

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy,  at x=0 is continous

Comment: The question is about the Riemann integral, so the Darboux integral won't help. C is definitely the right answer.

Comment: What does it mean in (C).... at any interval containing x?

Comment: This question does not make any sense. The way this question is phrased, only option D is correct. Since $0$ is the only point it's continuous, every interval which contains $0$ will have points of discontinuity.

Comment: @PankajTiwari It's asking continuity at x=0 and Riemann integrability on interval containing 0..as it is continuous at x=0.. Option D is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Take any partition $P$ of the interval $(a, b) \subset [-1, 1]$ with $0 \in (a, b)$ arbitrary. Clearly, the following holds $a < 0 < b$, therefore there exists $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ with $x_{n'}, x_{n' + 1} \in P$ s.t. $x_{n'} < 0$ and $x_{n' + 1} \geq 0$.
$$\begin{align*}
U(f, P) - L(f, P) &= \sum_{k = 1}^n(M_k - m_k)(x_k - x_{k - 1})\\
&=\sum_{k = 1}^{n'}(M_k - m_k)(x_k - x_{k - 1}) + \sum_{l=n' + 1}^n(M_l- m_l)(x_l - x_{l - 1})\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{n'}(0 - \sin(x_{k - 1}))(x_k - x_{k - 1}) + \sum_{l=n' + 1}^n\sin(x_l)(x_l - x_{l - 1}) \\
&=\sum_{k = 1}^{n'}(-1)\sin(x_{k - 1})(x_k - x_{k - 1}) +  \sum_{l=n' + 1}^n\sin(x_l)(x_l - x_{l - 1})  &(1) \\
&\geq \sum_{l=n' + 1}^n\sin(x_l)(x_l - x_{l - 1})  &(2)\\
&\geq \sum_{l=n' + 1}^n \cfrac{2}{\pi}x_l(x_l - x_{l - 1}) &(3)\\
&> 2/\pi\sum_{l=n' + 1}^n 1/2(x_l + x_{l - 1})(x_l - x_{l - 1})\\
&= 1/\pi\sum_{l=n' + 1}^n(x_l^2 - x_{l - 1}^2) = 1/\pi
\end{align*}$$
The left sum in the line (1) is greater than $0$, as each term is non-negative, i.e. $x_k - x_{k - 1} > 0$ for any $k \in [n]$, $-\sin(x_{k}) \geq 0$ for any $k \leq n'$. Also the inequality $\sin(x) \geq 2/\pi\cdot x$ for any $0 < x < \pi/2$ was used in the line $(2)$. Finally, note that the inequality $x_l > 1/2(x_l + x_{l - 1})$ for any $l > n' + 1$ was used in line $(3)$. Hence, we conclude that $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: I think you have to show that it is greater than a positive number not just 0, otherwise f may be integrable....

Comment: @dmtri indeed you're right, I added a positive number and it appeared to be $1/\pi$

Comment: The inequality $\sin x\ge 2/πx$ is not valid in $(0, 2 π)$

Comment: @dmtri it is valid for $(0, \pi/2)$

Comment: @dmtri you can check this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596634/mean-value-theorem-frac2-pi-frac-sin-xx1

Comment: Thanks for the reference . Now it must be $b\le 2/π$ and the final sum should be $4/π^3$

Comment: Can you please clarify what $b$ you are talking about

Comment: It is the b in the interval (a, b) you have defined...

Comment: Oh ok, in this case $x_l \leq b < 1 < \pi/2$ and we have $\sin(x_l) > \cfrac{2}{\pi}x_l$

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is odd in $[-1,1]$ so it suffices to prove that it is not integradable in $[0,1]$. Clearly $L(f,P)=0$ for every partition $P$. But then if we take the partition $P_n$ of the interval $[0,1]$ with step $\frac{1}{n}$, we would have $\begin{align*}
U(f,P_n)
&=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin(\frac {k}{n} )\\
&= \sin(1/2) \frac{1}{n}\left(\sin(1/2)\cot(1/2n)+\cos(1/2)\right)
\end{align*}$
Taking the limit of the above expresion we get $1-\cos 1>0$. That proves the fact that $f$ is not integradable.