# Spivak, Ch. 23, "Infinite Series", Problem 1(xiv): How do we show that $\sin{(1/n)}>\frac{1}{2n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the infinite series

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin{(1/n)}=\sin{(1)}+\sin{(1/2)}+\sin{(1/3)}+...\tag{1}$$

Figuring out if this converges is item (xiv) of problem 1 in Chapter 23 of Spivak's *Calculus*.

**Here is my attempted solution**

Let $f(x)=\sin{(1/x)}$. This function is positive and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$.

The sequence being summed is

$$a_n=\sin{(1/n)}=f(n)$$

If we write $\sin$ as an infinite series and integrate we find

$$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \sin{(1/x)}=\infty$$

Hence, by the integral test for infinite series, the series in (1) does not converge.

**Then I looked at the solution manual and all it says is**

> Divergent, since
>
> $$\sin{(1/n)}>\frac{1}{2n}\tag{2}$$

**How do we know that (2) is true?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean Value Theorem: $\frac{2}{\pi}<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596634/mean-value-theorem-frac2-pi-frac-sin-xx1)

Comment: To show the divergence of the series, we only need to show that $\sin{\frac1n}>\frac{1}{2n}$ for large $n$. Note that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\frac1x=1>\frac12$, so there must be a positive number $M>0$ such that $x\sin\frac1x>\frac12$ for $x>M$, and then we have $\sin{\frac1n}>\frac{1}{2n}$ for $n>M$.

Answer (score 0):

Using my favored $1,400^+$ years old approximation
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0\leq x\leq\pi$$ So, making $x=\frac 1 n$ compute
$$I_p=\int_1^p \frac{16 (\pi  n-1)}{\pi  n (5 \pi  n-4)+4} \,dn$$
$$I_p=\frac{4 \left(2 \log (\pi  p (5 \pi  p-4)+4)+3 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4} (2-5 \pi  p)\right)-2 \log (4+\pi  (5 \pi
   -4))+3 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4} (5 \pi -2)\right)\right)}{5 \pi }$$

Expanding as a series for large $p$
$$I_p=\frac{16}{5 \pi }\log(p)+\frac{2 \left(-3 \pi +4 \log \left(\frac{5 \pi ^2}{4+\pi  (5 \pi
   -4)}\right)+6 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{4} (5 \pi
   -2)\right)\right)}{5 \pi }+O\left(\frac{1}{p}\right)$$ The constant term is quite small $(\sim -0.12)$.