# Show that an integral is more than $\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{r+1}}{r+2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, integral-inequality

> Q. Consider the function $$f(r)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x^r\sin(x)dx.$$ Show that $f(r)>\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{r+1}}{r+2}.$

I do not know how to even begin. Actually, the first part of this question was to show that $f(r)<\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{r+1}}{r+1}.$ I was able to do this by noting that for $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right), x^r\sin(x)<x^r.$ But I do not know how to show that $f(r)>\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{r+1}}{r+2}.$

Comment: Note that $f(0)= 1$

Comment: You can try to show that $$\frac{1}{\pi/2}x^{r+1}<x^{r}\sin\left(x\right)<x^{r}$$ for $x \in (0,\pi/2)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=x\ cos x -\sin x$. For $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$, $f'(x)=-x \sin x < 0$. Hence, $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$, and as a result, $f(x)< f(0)=0$.

Now, consider the function $g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$. We have:

$$g'(x)=\frac{x \cos x -\sin x}{x^2}=\frac{f(x)}{x^2}< 0;$$

as a result, $g(x)$ is decreasing if $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}).$ Therefore:

$$g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x} > g(\frac{\pi}{2})=\frac{2}{\pi}. $$

Finally,

$$\frac{2}{\pi}x^{r+1}<x^r \sin x < x^r.$$

The rest is easy.

---

**PS:** There is a post containing the very same inequality at [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596634/mean-value-theorem-frac2-pi-frac-sin-xx1).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find a simple lower bound for $\dfrac{\sin x}x$ in the interval of interest...